# What is the earliest instance of a celebrity endorsement of a commercial product?

Tags: consumer-goods, advertising

Celebrity endorsements of various products, such as perfumes, soft drinks, or cars, are commonplace today. What is the earliest instance of such an occurrence? I’m considering a celebrity endorsement to be for a commercial product that

- Was not created by the celebrity
- Uses their name and/or testimony to promote sales
- Isn’t part of an exclusive contract involving the celebrity (e.g. it’s not a celebrity endorsement for a government official to commission guns for an army and then encourage its use)

If I missed any loopholes, assume I mean the clear definition of “celebrity X thinks this product is great, and so you should get it too.” What is the earliest instance of such an endorsement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebrity_branding#History

Comment: If the cited Wikipedia page answers the question, then it is out of scope.  If not, the question should explain why.

Comment: The Wikipedia page gives a rough idea but is not very specific (date, person) and has insufficient citations I think.